# remove part of a string and show it on the map

Tags: javascript, web-applications

Let's say that I got this string: `school_name = 'hello you world';`

When I show this on the google map, it works.

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: school_name,
        icon: image,
        map: myMap.getMap()
    });
```

But after I remove the you from the string using this: `school_name = school_name.split('you');`
it doesn't work: my google map marker will be gone and it goes to a default map.

Why does the split string not work?

Comment: sorry if i made any mistakes here. i'm new to this and not sure what tag to use and where to post it

Comment: The JavaScript `.split()` method does not do what you think it does. Calling `.split('you')` returns an array of strings formed by using "you" to delimit them. The result will be the array of two strings `['hello ', ' world']` and Google Maps does not take an array as a title - it takes a string.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `.split()` method does not do what you think it does. It is not for removing part of a string and returning a modified string - it is for splitting up a string according to a given delimeter and returning an array containing all the parts of the string.

Calling `.split('you')` returns an array of strings formed by using "you" to delimit them. The result of calling it on the string 'hello you world' will be the array of two strings `['hello ', ' world']`

Needless to say, Google Maps does not take an array in that `title` field - it takes a string.

What you might like to try is:

```
school_name = school_name.replace('you', '')
```